# Implement guild command testing in cog slash commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to learn discord.py V2.0. If I create a slash command without entering a guild to use then I takes some time before discord updated the bot slash command list. The qustion is how should I provide the guilds in my cog python file?

Here is my main.py:

```py
import os
import asyncio
#---
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
#---

MY_GUILD = discord.Object(id=1041079018713260173)
TOKEN = "token goes here"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

class abot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *, intents: discord.Intents):
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        self.bot = bot
        self.synced = False
        self.tree = app_commands.CommandTree(self.bot)

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.tree.sync(guild=MY_GUILD)
        self.synced = True

async def load():
    print("---Cogs---")
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
            print(f'[i]: Loaded "{filename}" into cogs')

async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is the event.py file inside of "cogs" folder:

```py
import asyncio
import os
#---
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

status = "testar bara..."
MY_GUILD = discord.Object(id=1041079018713260173) 

class events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("---Info---")
        print(f'Logged in as | "{self.bot.user}" | and is now online!')
        await self.bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(status))
        print(f'Updated status to -> "{status}"')
        print("Running and listening for commands....")
        print(f"----")

    @app_commands.command(name = "latency", description="brrarar testar")
    async def latencyf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"test... test...")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(events(bot))
```

Comment: **1.** Don't auto-sync. Remove the `tree.sync()` call from your `on_ready`. Do it in a message command instead. **2.** Don't change presence in `on_ready`, just pass it to your `Client`'s `__init__`...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to provide the guilds yourself. You can use `bot.guilds`, which provides a list of all the guilds where the bot is connected to.

Comment: Could you provide a example of how my code would look like?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. If it should apply to only one guild, then you should still add a new variable with that `guild id`. Otherwise you can access it with `self.bot.guilds`

Comment: I have a couple of servers that I want the commands to sync to. The problem is I dont know where I should put the guilds id or self.bot.guilds in my code for it to sync to these servers :)